# Why this loop only save in DB the last em.persist()?

Tags: loops, jpa, persistence, persist

```
                   for (long i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                    t.setnewerDate(sql);  
                    em.persist(t);
                    sql = new java.sql.Date( sql.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000);
                    System.out.println(sql); 
                   }
                em.flush();
                em.getTransaction().commit();
                em.close();
```

Any idea of how could I save diferent "t" objects 12 times?

Thanks in advance ;)

This either works:

```
 tx.begin();
                tres t = new tres();
                for (long i = 0; i < diffDays+1; i++) {
                t.setnwerDate(sql);  
                em.persist(t);
                sql = new java.sql.Date( sql.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000);
                System.out.println(sql);
                em.flush();
                tx.commit();
                tx.begin();

            }
```

Comment: You only have one instance of your entity `t`, you need to create a new instance inside your loop...

Comment: But I change the value of "sql" in each loop interaction....

Comment: Yes, so the _single instance_ of `t` gets a new date each time, but there's still only one instance...

Comment: And is no possible use the same item "t" with a change and store this item??

Comment: T is an entity, when you persist it, it becomes managed and its state is recorded.  On each iteration, you are changing the state of the managed T instance, when what you seem to want is to create a new instance.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate t inside the for loop. Otherwise you are just overwriting that objects how for the amount of iterations.

```
for (long i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

             WhateverTIs t = new WhateverTIs();

            t.setnewerDate(sql);  
            em.persist(t);
            sql = new java.sql.Date( sql.getTime() + 24*60*60*1000);
            System.out.println(sql); 
                   }

                em.flush();
                em.getTransaction().commit();
                em.close();
```